# formatting an entire line in ruby given multiple arguments

Tags: ruby

For my program, I have a list of things that's sort of like a spreadsheet that I'm trying to print to the console. I want it to look something like

```
garage 1
   car:         jaguar
   price:     $134,000

   car:       mercedes
   price:     $234,000

garage 2
   car:         jaguar
   price:     $134,000
```

`garage` is a hash with each key being garage number and cars in a specific garage being pushed to each key, eg `garage[0] = [car1, car2]` 
Class `car` holds the information printed, and has these definitions

```
class Car
   attr_accessor :car_name, :car_price
   def initialization(name, price)
      @car_name = name
      @car_price = price
   end

   def name
      @car_name
   end

   def price
      @car_price
   end
end
```

I've tried to implement such

```
garage.each do |x|
            print "garage "
            print garage.index(x) + 1
            puts " "
            x.each do |y|
               printf("%10s", "Car: ")
               puts y.name.rjust(16)
               printf("%10s", "Price: $")
               puts y.price.to_s.rjust(16)
               puts " "
            end
end
```

But I'm not getting the desired output. Depending on the car name, the spaces in between will be too far and the output won't be aligned. 
I'm wondering if there's a method where I can format an entire line output? Basically like chaining together strings and other variables such as integers and floats and setting their distances correctly so that I can customize each line that's output to console.

Comment: The key is to learn about `printf` [format specifiers](https://www.rubyguides.com/2012/01/ruby-string-formatting/).

Answer (score 0):

First create the `Car` class:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :car_name, :car_price
  def initialize(name, price)
    @car_name = name
    @car_price = price
  end
end
```

Note that the method is `initialize`, not `initialization`, and that the class method `attr_accessor` creates both getter and setter methods for each of the two instance variables, so there is no need for the explicit getter methods.

Now let's create a couple of instances of this class.

```
jag = Car.new('jaguar', 134000)
  #=> #<Car:0x00007f839690d2d0 @car_name="jaguar", @car_price=134000>
mb  = Car.new('mercedes', 234000)
  #=> #<Car:0x00007f83990b1d90 @car_name="mercedes", @car_price=234000>
```

Suppose the hash `garage` is as follows.

```
garage = { 1=>[jag, mb], 2=>[jag] }
  #=> {1=>[#<Car:0x00007f839690d2d0 @car_name="jaguar", @car_price=134000>,
  #=>      #<Car:0x00007f83990b1d90 @car_name="mercedes", @car_price=234000>],
  #    2=>[#<Car:0x00007f839690d2d0 @car_name="jaguar", @car_price=134000>]}
```

Firstly, we will need a way to display car prices in the correct format, starting with a dollar sign and with thousands separated by commas. One way to do that is as follows.

```
def convert_price_to_str(car_price)
  s = ''
  loop do
    car_price, three = car_price.divmod(1000)
    break "$#{three}#{s}" if car_price.zero?
    s = (",%03d" % three) + s
  end
end
```

For example,

```
convert_price_to_str      34  #=>        "$34"
convert_price_to_str    3042  #=>     "$3,042"
convert_price_to_str   49621  #=>    "$49,621"
convert_price_to_str 1324534  #=> "$1,324,534"
```

See [Integer#divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-divmod), a very handy (and underutilized) method.

To display the values in the desired format it is necessary to determine the length of the longest car name or formatted price.

```
longest = garage.values.flatten.map do |car|
  [car.car_name.size, convert_price_to_str(car.car_price).size].max
end.max
  #=> 8
```

Now let's write another helper method to display car names and prices.

```
def print_name_and_price(name, price, longest)
  puts "   car:       #{name.rjust(longest)}"
  puts "   price:     #{convert_price_to_str(price).rjust(longest)}"
  puts
end
```

For example,

```
print_name_and_price('jaguar', 134000, longest)
```

displays the three lines (the last being empty):

```
  car:         jaguar
  price:     $134,000
```

See [String#rjust](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-rjust).

We may now put all this together.

```
garage.each do |g,cars|
  puts "garage #{g}"
  cars.each do |car|
    print_name_and_price(car.car_name, car.car_price, longest)
  end
end
```

displays:

```
garage 1
   car:         jaguar
   price:     $134,000

   car:       mercedes
   price:     $234,000

garage 2
   car:         jaguar
   price:     $134,000
```

Comment: Ah so I guess my real question was how to determine correct spacing, but that method you called to find the longest string in my hash is how to do it. I have a question then, what exactly does `garage.values.flatten.map` do exactly?

Comment: In IRB compute `a = garage.values`, then`b = a.flatten` then`b.map { |car| [car.car_name.size, convert_price_to_str(car.car_price).size] }`, then `b.map { |car| [car.car_name.size, convert_price_to_str(car.car_price).size].max }` and then you will know.